# Flutter doctor no me reconoce el complemento de flutter y dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy teniendo problemas al instalar flutter junto con dart,  Instale android studio sin problemas, y también descargue e instale los  plugin de flutter y dart sin problemas en android studio, pero al  momento de ejecutar flutter doctor me arroja que no tengo instalado  ambos plugin, adjunto el error para ver si alguien me puede ayudar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si tienes android studio instalado, vete sdk manager y busca los paquetes flutter y dart

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo! Instalé los pligins Flutter y Dart en Android Studio, pero ni el Flutter Doctor ni el Visual Studio Code me los reconocen! Ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Hola si no has tenido suerte te invito a ejecutar los siguientes comandos, el error que presentas es un issue que ya se había solucionado en la versión 1.22 con android studio 4.1.0 pero debido a la actualización de android studio a la versión 4.1.1 hay que actualizar el canal de Flutter.

flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
flutter doctor -v

- El 1ro te cambiara el canal estable de flutter al canal de desarrollo
- El 2do hará una actualización de tu flutter 1.22 a la 1.25 actualmente quizás cuando lo ejecutes este una versión mayor.
- El 3ro configura la ruta de instalación de Android-Studio
- El 4to aplicará los cambios correspondientes.

Espero te sirva saludos

Answer (score 0):

Solo una vez q flutter doctor muestre q los plugins no están instalados escribir:

```
flutter channel dev
```

Y luego:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Luego otra vez `flutter doctor` como para q actualice los cambios y listo...

Debería funcionar.